# How to return the reference of a declared vector in the method body?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I have this method :

```cpp
vector<float> MyObject::getResults(int n = 1000)
{
    vector<float> results(n, 0);
    // do some stuff
    return results;
}
```

Of course this is not optimized and I want to return a reference of this vector but I cannot simply do this :

```cpp
const vector<float>& MyObject::getResults(int n = 1000)
{
    vector<float> results(n, 0);
    // do some stuff
    return results;
}
```

This doesn't work, the vector will be destroy at the end of method because it's a local variable.

So the only solution I found to solve this problem is to create a private vector in MyObject and return a reference to this vector :

```cpp
const vector<float>& MyObject::getResults(int n = 1000)
{
    this->results.clear();
    this->results.resize(n, 0);
    // do some stuff
    return results;
}
```

Is this the right way to do that? Do you have any other solution to propose?

Comment: Make the vector a member variable.

Comment: Whats the problem with returning by copy? NRVO will take care of that.

Comment: It is already the solution that I propose but I look if there are better solutions. Moreover clean and resize my vector take more time than to recreate a new one.

Comment: I do not know how NRVO works. I will inquire about this. Thanks.

Comment: _"Of course this is not optimized"_ It specifically **is**! As said, look NRVO up.

Comment: Ok but NRVO can not be used in any case, how to know that NRVO has been used? I will check that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What's most efficient?

**Return by value. Don't worry, no copying occurs.** This is best practice:

```
// Use this
vector<float> getResults(int n = 1000);
```

**Why is this?** Local variables returned from a function **are not copied**. They are moved into the location where the return value will be stored:

```
// Result moved into v; no copying occurs
vector<float> v = getResults(); 

// Result moved into memory allocated by new; no copying occurs
vector<float>* q = new vector<float>(getResults());
```

## How does this work?

When a function returns an object, it returns it in one of two ways:

- In the registers
- In memory

You can only return simple objects like `int`s and `double`s in the registers. For values returned in memory, the function is passed a pointer to the location that it needs to place the return value.

When you call  `new vector<float>(getResults());`, the following things happen:

- The computer allocates memory for a new vector
- It gives the location of that memory to `getResults()`, along with any other parameters.
- `getResults` constructs the vector *in that memory*, no need to copy.

## What about returning a reference to a member variable?

Generally speaking, this is a *premature optimization* that *may not provide much, or any, benefit*, and *it makes your code more complex and more prone to bugs*.

If you assign the output of `getResults` to a vector, then the data will get copied anyways:

```
MyObject m; 
vector<float> = m.getResults(); // if getResults returns a const reference, the data gets copied
```

On the other hand, if you assign the output of `getResults` to a `const reference`, this can make managing the lifetime of `MyObject` much more complex. In the below example, *the reference you return is invalidated as soon as the function ends* because `m` gets destroyed.

```
vector<float> const& evilDoNotUseThisFunction() {
    MyObject m;
    vector<float> const& ref = m.getResults();
    return ref; // This is a bug - ref is invalid when m gets destroyed
}
```

## What's the difference between copying and moving for `std::vector`?

**Copying loops over all the elements of a vector.** When a vector is copied, all the data stored by the vector gets copied:

```
vector<float> a = getVector(); // Get some vector

vector<float> b = a // Copies a
```

This is equivalent to the following code:

```
vector<float> a = getVector(); // Get some vector

vector<float> b(a.size()); // Allocate vector of size a

// Copy data; this is O(n)
float* data = b.data();
for(float f : a) {
    *data = f;
    data++;
}
```

**Moving doesn't loop over any elements.** When a vector is constructed by `move`, it's as though it's swapped with an empty vector:

```
vector<float> a = getVector(); // Get some vector

vector<float> b = std::move(a); // Move a into b
```

is equivalent to:

```
vector<float> a = getVector(); // Get some vector

vector<float> b; // Make empty vector (no memory allocated)

std::swap(a, b); // Swap a with b; very fast; this is O(1)
```

**TL;DR: Copying copies all the data in a loop. Moving just swaps out who owns the memory.**

**How do we know `results` gets moved?** C++11 requires that local variables get moved *automatically* when they're returned. You don't have to call `move`.

**Does a swap actually occur?** In many cases, no. A swap is already cheap, but **the compiler can be clever and optimize out the swap entirely.** It does this by constructing your `results` vector in the memory where it'll be returning `results`. This is called Named Return Value Optimization. See https://shaharmike.com/cpp/rvo/#named-return-value-optimization-nrvo

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, just a quick question. What is the difference in **copied** and **moved**?

Comment: What is the difference between copying and moving in English? One makes a duplicate (and then in this case destroys the original), and the other ... moves the storage from one variable to another with no copying. Specifically using the [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) instead of the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: I added a section explaining the difference!

Comment: Side note: Swapping is a possible implementation, but not a necessary one. The moved-from vector is left in an unspecified, but valid state. GCC, for instance, deletes the previous memory of the moved-to vector, leaving the moved-from as empty (with no capacity)...

Answer (score 0):

> Of course this is not optimized

It's fine. Specifically, since C++11 you don't need to do anything extra here.

In any case you should worry about optimization only after you have something that is correct, and a way to profile it.

Anyway, returning a reference to a private vector is less than ideal - it extends the lifetime of the vector unnecessarily, and may lead to re-entrancy problems later, like any other stateful function.